# How to make view effect when cropping UIImage like IOS 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When the user is  cropping photo ,the crop area is bright and other area is a little dark ,I want to know how to make this?Anyone can give me some advice will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: use alpha effect for the same.

Comment: I can change the whole view's alpha,but I don't know how to keep the crop area's alpha as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two image views, position both on top of each other, have the lower one at a low alpha and the top one at an alpha of 1.0. When resizing, simply crop the top image which will show the lower one behind it giving the effect you want.

**UPDATE:** Have added an image to illustrate...

[image]

Comment: But the effect still not  solve the problem that I want the crop area view alpha to be 1.0.

Comment: That's what I said, re-read my suggestion... the TOP view is alpha 1.0 and this is the one you crop.

Comment: I am sorry ,I am not realy get you point .I mean when cropping ,the TOP view is alpha 1.0,and it will be hide the lower one .I just don't know how to show the low alpha view behind the top one.and I also have a crop view on the top of the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, take a uiview and call it as cropview. Now when the Image is captured and you need to crop the image,set the cropview.alpha=0.5 and it will be shown in somewhat this manner as I have implemented in my app. Hope that helps you. [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but I want the effect like the ios 5.

Comment: Can you provide some screen shot?

Comment: [Here](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html)At Photos title you can see the effect.

Comment: So you want the corner grab indicators and the 'thirds' overlay?

Comment: YES.I just didn't frigure out how to make this.